# is there a basic custom application with Apex classes and a few visualforce pages to get started?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am looking to jump-start custom application development for salesforce. I am hoping that there is a skeletal apex application (similar to basic hello world web apps for j2ee or node.js platform) that  I could import into my Eclipse ( with Force.com plugin) and begin incrementally adding  pages and features.

Answer (score 2):

[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_intro) is best guide for interactive learning.

Another good option is [apex](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjw0sq5zurSAhWDtBoKHTK-BGEQFgg0MAE&usg=AFQjCNH0UNz-14j75BpYw0NB6DiZvIppqw&sig2=IcxA54QueyhklXQuE5BBaQ) and [visualforce](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi1wIXKzurSAhUDChoKHaB6CDYQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNFBtF195Cq9nwYPS3wX5sutnK0ZKQ&sig2=YrdlWqS-cf4Ldojln_ACmQ) guide.

Comment: I have used trailhead tutorials and also viewed the apex and visualforce guides. I still don't know how to create a custom application package.

Comment: What do you mean by package? Here you can simple install ide of your choice and create a project with entering your orgs credentials. Then it'd be connected to your Salesforce environment where you could start creating your application.

Comment: by package , I mean a managed package which I could put on appexchange and have others try it out in their org.

Comment: Packages are being created from setup menu of salesforce. Eclipse is only for updating your code. You can find enough information over the web about it. I could not find package related question in your original question, so from next time please add sufficient information to your question.